# Solving a Recurrence relation without iteration

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, recurrence, big-o

How do I Solve this ?

T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + cn

Ans is  \theta(nLogn)

How this answer can be achieved using master theorem or any other effecient method?

Comment: Yes, there is. Gererating functions. It's far too broad for [so]. Google it on wikipedia. It gives a pretty good intro to the topic.

Comment: Can we use master theorem here ?

Comment: @RohitRoy No, master theorem can't be used here, its better to use recursion tree here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursion tree for the given recursion will look like this:

```
                                Size                        Cost

                                 n                           n
                               /   \
                             n/4   3n/4                      n
                           /   \     /    \
                        n/16  3n/16 3n/16  9n/16             n

                        and so on till size of input becomes 1
```

The longes simple path from root to  a leaf would be n-> 3n/4 -> (3/4) ^2 n .. till 1

```
 Therefore  let us assume the height of tree = k

            ((3/4) ^ k )*n = 1 meaning  k = log to the base 4/3 of n

 In worst case we expect that every level gives a cost of  n and hence 

        Total Cost = n * (log to the base 4/3 of n)

 However we must keep one thing in mind that ,our tree is not complete and therefore

 some levels near the bottom would be partially complete.

 But in asymptotic analysis we ignore such intricate details.

 Hence in worst Case Cost = n * (log to the base 4/3 of n)

          which  is O( n * log n )
```

Now, let us verify this using substitution method:

```
 T(n) =  O( n * log n)  iff T(n) < = dnlog(n) for some d>0

 Assuming this to be true:

 T(n) = T(n/4) + T(3n/4) + n

      <= d(n/4)log(n/4) + d(3n/4)log(3n/4) + n

       = d*n/4(log n  - log 4 )  + d*3n/4(log n  - log 4/3) + n

       = dnlog n  - d(n/4)log 4 - d(3n/4)log 4/3  + n

       = dnlog n  - dn( 1/4(log 4)  -  3/4(log 4/3)) + n

       <= dnlog n

       as long as d >=  1/( 1/4(log 4)  -  3/4(log 4/3) )
```

Comment: Nice explanation, But why we cannot use master here ?  the quation can be rewritten as T(n) = 2T(3n/4) + cn in case for worst time complexity. And then we can use master

Comment: @MohitKumar How will you transform given recurrence to any of the three cases? Thats why.

Comment: it may not be the case